# Can a structural directive refer to a child component using @ContentChild?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

If I have a custom directive `ParentDirective` and custom component `ChildComponent` arranged like so:

```
<div appParent>
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

...then I can use `@ContentChild` in the directive to refer to the component:

```
@ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1kudjy) where this is working. (It logs to the console to show that the `child` member is set).

However, if I change appParent into a *structural* directive, then the `child` member is never set.

```
<div *appParent>
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hrsac).

**Is it not possible to use `@ContentChild` with structural directives?**

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't test, but does it work with ViewChild?

Comment: @IngoBürk: No. Would you expect it to? As I understand it, `@ViewChild` gives access to components directly within the view of a component - not to the content that gets rendered therein.

Comment: I was thinking that it might due to the way a structural directive desugars into a template on its own wherein the child seems more of a view child than a content child to me. But seems like you got an answer now anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you cannot, and that is due to the design used by angular for both type of directives. Creating a directive via `TemplateRef` and injecting it via `createEmbeddedView` of `ViewContainerRef` **generates the template as a sibling in the dom, not as a child**. Therefore, Angular's injection also respects this so the child and the place of creation cannot see each other. You can draw it in your mind as an extra added layer there.

**[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.1.1/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L321)** is the source code of the `createEmbeddedView`

```
  createEmbeddedView(context: any): EmbeddedViewRef<any> {
    return new ViewRef_(Services.createEmbeddedView(
        this._parentView, this._def, this._def.element !.template !, context));
  }
```

As you can see, it returns a new `ViewRef` where it injects your `context`.

[**More details here.**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15998)

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not really the answer I *wanted*, but it's good to know.