# Structural directive get child directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to access a 'child' directive inside a structural directive so that I can inject some data in that directive. But this always results in undefined or an injection error.

I have the following html:

```
<app-table [dataSource]="data">
  <button *customColumn="let row" [highlightRowOnClick]="row">
    click here!
  </button>
</app-table>
```

I want to inject all the rows via the `customColumn` into the `[highlightRowOnClick]` directive, so that it can deselect all the other rows on click of the current row

How I would like to pass all rows to the directive: 
(`app-table` --> `*customColumn` --> `[highlightRowOnClick]`).

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufdi2y) reproducing this problem with row selection working, but not row deselection.

---

**My Toughts**

- I know that I cannot access the child components via `@ContentChildren`, due to the `[highlightRowOnClick]` directive not being a direct child, but more a sibling in the view ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560347/can-a-structural-directive-refer-to-a-child-component-using-contentchild)).
- I know a structural directive can select it's host element (an attribute directive for example, see [ngSwtich](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts), via the `@Host` decorator), but this doesn't work the other way arround. This results in an Injector error (`no provider for 'customColumn' found`). ([this is described here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15998))
- I can use a service to inject the data, but that could create bugs when there is more then one table within the current view (since the service is a single instance and rows could be exactly the same, some rows can override eachother, causing weird selection issues (selections happening in both tables for example)).
- I can inject the rows directily into the `[highlightRowOnClick]` directive, but this would require the programmer to do this every time. In my opinion it makes sense that you only want to highlight the current row and I also don't want to expose all the rows to the programmer on that place, since he already has access to them via the `[dataSouce]`. so I think this is not the best solution.

*Example:*

```
<app-table [dataSource]="rows">
  <button *customColumn="let row; let rows=rows" [highlightRowOnClick]="row" allRows="rows">
    click here!
  </button>
</app-table>
```

Does anyone know of a better way I can resolve this? Or maby a whole different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you has all in a wrapper component you can inject it in the HighlightRowOnClickDirective

```
constructor(@Optional() @Host() private wrap:WrapperComponent ){}
  @Input('highlightRowOnClick')
  row: Row;

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    this.wrap.dataSource.forEach(x=>{
      x.isSelected=(x==this.row)
    })
  }
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fx5jfk?file=src/app/wrapper/highlight-row-on-click.directive.ts)

But really I don't know the reason to not use a variable "indexSelected" and use a `*ngFor="...;let i=index"`and pass as argument

**Update** using Index Select.

We can to have a variable in row "isSelected" or a unique variable in the wrapper "indexSelected", and pass as value the index

```
<div *ngFor="let row of dataSource;let i=index">
  <div [class.selected]="i==indexSelected"> Hello world! </div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of colHeaders">
     <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="col.template; context: { $implicit: i }"></ng-template>
  </ng-container>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

The directive becomes

```
 @Input('highlightRowOnClick')index:number

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    this.wrap.indexSelected=this.index
  }
```

see [another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rulnk9?file=src/app/wrapper/highlight-row-on-click.directive.ts)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this solution! 
What do you mean with the 'indexSelected' variable? I think exposing all the rows to the user on that place is not a good way to go, since the user should only have control over the rows in the `[dataSource]`

Comment: Ah I see. Providing the row is better, because you can then pass the rowdata into a function (Angular material options menu for example (https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)). But thanks for the insight!