# How to use a directive method from a child element of component?

Tags: angular

I want to create a directive that allows me to show or hide a component based on a condition validated in a service, aditionally some child element of component would be able of execute a method of the directive.
I want to be able of use something like this, but I get an error `No directive found with exportAs 'showNotification'.`

```html
  <app-alert #myNotification="showNotification" *showNotification="'myNot'">
    <!-- How to call a method from this element? -->
    <button (click)="myNotification.hide('myNot')">Dismiss notification</button>
  </app-alert>
```

The directive would be used in any component or element, with the minimum setup required, directly from template. It's like an `ngIf` that validate the condition in a service.

Here is an Stackblitz with an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5dgxat?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11189

Comment: You could also create child directive, which would access parent through Dependency Incejction.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, that point me out to the answer, I preffer the method of "de-sugar" commented in the link of @Chelleppan instead of child directive suggested by Bojan for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the button in a component and inject a service into that component.
Inject the same service into your structural directive and you can communicate between them via the service.

However, if you need to communicate between your button and the *instance* of the structural directive that's on the parent - I don't think that's possible with a structural directive [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560347/can-a-structural-directive-refer-to-a-child-component-using-contentchild).

In that case I would create a component to wrap app-alert (instead of using the structural directive), and I would inject a reference to this component into app-alert. app-alert could then call methods on the parent component.